# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray , jsonObject.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA) did not worked

Tags: java, android

My app can't get data from server.

Every solution that I found in the internet did not work.

```java
private static final String KEY_DATA = "data";

HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
            temp.put("nome",textoDigitado);

HttpJsonParser httpJsonParser = new HttpJsonParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = httpJsonParser.makeHttpRequest(BASE_URL+"fetch_single_bar.php","GET",temp);

JSONArray bares_json;

if (success == 1){

     bares_json = jsonObject.getJSONArray(KEY_DATA);

}
```

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"id":17,"nome":"bar teste","cidade":"cidade teste","estado":"estado teste","conectados":"0"} at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

The response of search in navigators is:

```
{"success":1,"data":{"id":17,"nome":"bar teste","cidade":"cidade teste","estado":"estado teste","conectados":"0"}}
```

Comment: That's a map, not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can parse  `JSONObject`to `JSONArray`. But first of all, is a lot easier to get a respond using **Volley**,(that's a suggest).

What you just need to do is `JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("KEY_DATA");`.

The `jsonObject.get("KEY_DATA")` returns a Object.

Volley is a Async library which hepls you out with server responds and it's a lot easier than what i've seen in others libraries.

Comment: Why is async helpful in this situation?

Comment: it's helpful because you really don't know when the server will respond for several reasons as: the net is slow, too much data in the database, etc.

when you use Volley, you gotta Override two methods which are "onRespondListener"   (this one is for the respond of the server and inside of this one you write all what you want to do when the data comes)   and "onErrorListener" (when something wrong happens here gives you a exepction)

if you are going to use it.... search for  "StringRequest".

Comment: Ahhh, Volley is a client-side library for Android... I missed that part and assumed it would be running on the server

Comment: hahaha,yeah it's a client-side library.

what i use to get the data from the databse in the server is Spring-boot. i use it with NetBeant IDE, so with volley in my android app I access to that Spring-boot project and get the data.

Answer (score 0):

your data field in Json is JSONObject not JSONArray make following changes

```
  if (success == 1){

         bares_json = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"id":17,"nome":"bar
>   teste","cidade":"cidade teste","estado":"estado
>   teste","conectados":"0"} at data of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be
>   converted to JSONArray

==> Because you are casting JSONObject into the JSONArray. Because "data" is JSONObject.

```
{"success":1,"data":{"id":17,"nome":"bar teste","cidade":"cidade teste","estado":"estado teste","conectados":"0"}}
```

### Solution:

```
JSONObject bares_json;

if (success == 1){

     bares_json = jsonObject.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);

}
```